# How does ecrecover get compiled?

Tags: solidity, evm, signature, bytecode

How does `ecrecover()` in solidity work? Looking at [ethervm.io](https://www.ethervm.io/) there doesn't seem to be an opcode for ecrecover? To what bytes is a `ecrecover()` call compiled?

Comment: There's a precompiled contract for that; see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/88238/16043).

Comment: Ah ok, ethereum has so many free bytes that they could use to build in those opcodes, why don't they?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-compiled contracts do not have an opcode but are rather run by making a message call to a particular address.

Ecrecover is a pre-compiled contract that is pointed at the address
`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001`